# Forms calling reports in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

Step1:  I open an Access form when the software opens.  It acts like a switchboard manager where the user can open other forms and reports.  (Popup = yes, modal = no)
Step2:  Click to open a "Master Form" which also has other options. (ditto)  So the original VB code called this form to be open and is still "running" in the background.
Step 3:  Click to open a report based on the record selected.

So now there's 2 forms open and 1 report.  User cannot toggle between them, must close one to get to the other (necessary).

On the open report, I would like to modify the rightclick commandbar.  However, "Close" doesn't work because Access now shows Form1 and Form2 above as gray and Access is locked.  I would like to be able to right-click to do a number of things including Close, Change to Design View, etc.  But if I'm locked out like this, none of these will work.

I searched on...
1.  Ending the background vba that's running - no luck
2.  Setting focus on the active screen name - no luck
3.  Setting focus on a control on the Form2 above - no luck
4.  Tried all kinds of CommandBar things, no luck (ID choice vs. manual OnAction) and many more

I'd be happy to attach what I'm doing but it's pretty big, although I could probably cut out the sections that this applies too...

I've been searching for about 16 hours now...  Anyone???

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

`Popup = Yes` in Access means two things:

1. The form or report stays above all other forms and reports that have `Popup = No` and above Access’ application window.
2. The form or report is not bound to the area of Access' application window and can be drawn outside of it.

You have two options:

1. Set `Popup = No` for the two forms. In this case they will be tied to the application window area.
2. Set `Popup = Yes` for the report as well, so that it can stand in front of the two forms.